# How to programmatically move a slider at a set duration using IOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios6, uislider

I have an iPhone application with a UISlider. When my user presses the play button, I want my slider to move from a value of 1, slowly, to a value of 100. The slider slides for the duration of the recording that gets played back when my user presses the play button.

I looked at the UISlider documentation. The only method that seems like it might help me is the `setValue:animated:` method. However, when animated=yes, the slider moves to value 100 way too fast.

Any way to slow it down a little?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can let the UIView animate itself rather than working out the tweening yourself, or writing callbacks. For Example, this animates the slider to it's maximum value from it's current value in 5 seconds. And it's a lot smoother than trying to do it yourself.

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    [sender setEnabled:NO];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
        self.slider.value = self.slider.maximumValue;
    }];
}
```

If you don't believe me - here's a [sample project that you can download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/585261/Slider.zip) to see it for yourself:

Comment: Thank you, that is a bit more smooth, and I can also set the duration much easier

Comment: It's not user interactable anymore though, I would like to be able to pause the recording if the user presses down on the slider, and I would like for the recording to resume at the proper place once the user let's go. You have a fix?

Comment: Get the current position and set the value to that. Have you looked at any of the core animation guides?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` which is part of [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to increment the slider more slowly. Increase the position of the slider on every tick. Something like this:

```
NSTimer *timerForSlider = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)updateSlider {
    [slider setValue:slider.value+1];
    if(slider.value == MAXIMUM_VALUE) {
        [timerForSlider invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! (although I also realized through this process that a slider's value is not 1 to 100, but 0 to 1)

Comment: @bmende You can configure the values to whatever you with the minimumValue and maximumValue properties

Comment: @Abizern has actually posted a better answer. A timer was the first thing I though of, but his solution is a lot smoother. It is the one I would use myself.